# Consul configuration file use templating

Tags: consul

I would like to assign the value of a key in the Consul configuration file based on the value of an environment variable.
consul-template has an `env` function that works well in my example when running a test.

```
# File template.txt
{{ env "HOSTNAME" }}
$ consul-template -template "template.txt:out.txt"
# out.txt
consul01
```

However when I try and put in templating functions inside the consul configuration I get an error saying: `expected: IDENT | STRING got: LBRACE`

There is an Hashicorp example that uses templating in the consul config:
https://github.com/hashicorp/learn-consul-vms/blob/main/service-mesh/deploy/config/consul-server.hcl
That function GetInterfaceIP does not seem to exist at all but at some point it seems like templating should have worked inside consul config files.
Am I missing something here or do I have to run a consul-template process first to get the config file generated correctly (which would not be optimal)?

Answer (score 1):

The daemon `consul-template` is just a way to populate values from Consul into the file system with additional bit of functionality, e.g. referencing to environment variables. `consul-template` depends on Consul when it comes to rendering a template file, therefore, you **can't use** it to render config of **the same Consul server** the daemon is associated with.

What you see in [this example configuration](https://github.com/hashicorp/learn-consul-vms/blob/main/service-mesh/deploy/config/consul-server.hcl#L8)

```
advertise_addr = "{{ GetInterfaceIP `eth1` }}"
```

is not actually `consul-template` syntax. Instead, it refers to the [go-sockaddr](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/go-sockaddr/template?utm_source=godoc) template that is resolved at runtime of the Consul server/agent. This became available in [Consul 1.1.0 and later](https://developer.hashicorp.com/consul/docs/agent/config/cli-flags#_advertise).